# T-SQL aliases scope within Pivot dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, subquery

My problem is that I would like to PIVOT some datas from a table subset of data linked to the current object. Therefore I would like to specify a WHERE condition as `[ForeignKey] = top.[Id]` but it won't let me access `top.[Id]` inside a subselect statement...

```
SELECT 
    o.[MemberId] AS 'Member',
    o.[Probability] AS 'Probability 1',
    o.[ProbabilitySec] AS 'Probability 2',
    p.[0], p.[1], p.[2], p.[3], p.[4], p.[5], p.[6], p.[7], p.[8], p.[9], p.[10], p.[11], p.[12], p.[13], p.[14], p.[15], p.[16], p.[17], p.[18], p.[19], p.[20], p.[21], p.[22], p.[23], p.[24], p.[25], p.[26], p.[27], p.[28], p.[29], p.[30], p.[31], p.[32], p.[33], p.[34], p.[35], p.[36], p.[37], p.[38], p.[39], p.[40], p.[41], p.[42], p.[43], p.[44], p.[45], p.[46], p.[47], p.[48], p.[49], p.[50], p.[51], p.[52], p.[53], p.[54], p.[55], p.[56], p.[57], p.[58], p.[59], p.[60], p.[61], p.[62], p.[63], p.[64], p.[65], p.[66], p.[67], p.[68], p.[69], p.[70], p.[71], p.[72], p.[73], p.[74], p.[75], p.[76], p.[77], p.[78], p.[79], p.[80], p.[81], p.[82], p.[83], p.[84], p.[85], p.[86], p.[87], p.[88], p.[89], p.[90], p.[91], p.[92], p.[93], p.[94], p.[95], p.[96], p.[97], p.[98], p.[99], p.[100]
FROM 
    [Outputs] o,
    (   
        SELECT [Percentile], [Value]
            FROM [Percentiles]
            WHERE [OutputId] = 1    -- BUG: o.[Id] doesn't work ???
    ) AS rp
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(rp.[Value])
        FOR rp.[Percentile] IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31], [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40], [41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [48], [49], [50], [51], [52], [53], [54], [55], [56], [57], [58], [59], [60], [61], [62], [63], [64], [65], [66], [67], [68], [69], [70], [71], [72], [73], [74], [75], [76], [77], [78], [79], [80], [81], [82], [83], [84], [85], [86], [87], [88], [89], [90], [91], [92], [93], [94], [95], [96], [97], [98], [99], [100])
    ) p;
```

Database schema:

[image]

Percentiles is a table that holds values for each percentile betweeen 0 and 100 for each Output record, therefore the data in it will looks like that:

```
 1  | 1 |  0  | 0.343
 2  | 1 |  1  | 0.678
 3  | 1 |  2  | 0.153
 4  | 1 |  3  | 0.753
 5  | 1 | ... | 0.154
101 | 1 | 100 | 0.834
102 | 2 |  0  | 0.182
103 | 2 |  1  | 0.724
104 | 2 |  2  | 0.692
105 | 2 |  3  | 0.341
106 | 2 | ... | 0.102
```

The purpose is to get all this percentiles as columns but only for a given OutputId (but I can't access the current OutputId with `o.Id` in the subselect used by the PIVOT.

For information, in the Outputs table, MemberId isn't a Foreign Key but just a stored identifier useful in the output.

Would you have any idea on how to link only the Percentiles used by the PIVOT where `[OutputId]` is equal to `o.[Id]` (at the moment, o isn't accessible in that scope)? Btw, it is the line with the comment in the code above.

Many thanks !

Comment: Post your sample data and expected ans or sqlfiddle

Comment: First of all, please stop using old style `JOIN`s.. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins. Second, why are you using a subselect if you could also do it with a regular JOIN and use the `[OutputId]=o.[Id]` as the `ON` clause?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you posted your table structures, sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought that my question was specific enough (accessing a table alias in another scope of the query) to avoid giving more details about the DB structure. I've fixed that by adding more details, hope this will help you helping me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received some help from a friend who solved my issue very quickly :) Thanks to her. In case of it can help somebody else, here is the fixed query with the link between Output and Percentiles working through the PIVOT.

```
SELECT 
    [ActivityId] AS 'Activity #',
    [MemberId] AS 'Member',
    [PValue] AS 'Plus Value',
    [Probability] AS 'Probability 1',
    [ProbabilitySec] AS 'Probability 2',
    p.[0], p.[1], p.[2], p.[3], p.[4], p.[5], p.[6], p.[7], p.[8], p.[9], p.[10], p.[11], p.[12], p.[13], p.[14], p.[15], p.[16], p.[17], p.[18], p.[19], p.[20], p.[21], p.[22], p.[23], p.[24], p.[25], p.[26], p.[27], p.[28], p.[29], p.[30], p.[31], p.[32], p.[33], p.[34], p.[35], p.[36], p.[37], p.[38], p.[39], p.[40], p.[41], p.[42], p.[43], p.[44], p.[45], p.[46], p.[47], p.[48], p.[49], p.[50], p.[51], p.[52], p.[53], p.[54], p.[55], p.[56], p.[57], p.[58], p.[59], p.[60], p.[61], p.[62], p.[63], p.[64], p.[65], p.[66], p.[67], p.[68], p.[69], p.[70], p.[71], p.[72], p.[73], p.[74], p.[75], p.[76], p.[77], p.[78], p.[79], p.[80], p.[81], p.[82], p.[83], p.[84], p.[85], p.[86], p.[87], p.[88], p.[89], p.[90], p.[91], p.[92], p.[93], p.[94], p.[95], p.[96], p.[97], p.[98], p.[99], p.[100]
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            o.[ActivityId],
            o.[MemberId],
            o.[Probability],
            o.[ProbabilitySec],
            sm.[PValue],
            rp.[Percentile],
            rp.[Value]
        FROM 
            [modeller].[Outputs] o
            INNER JOIN [core].[ScMember] sm
            ON sm.[Id] = o.[MemberId]
            INNER JOIN 
            (    
                SELECT [Percentile], [Value], [OutputId]
                FROM [modeller].[Percentiles]
            ) AS rp
            ON o.[Id] = rp.[OutputId]
    ) AS nested
    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(nested.[Value])
        FOR nested.[Percentile] IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31], [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40], [41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [48], [49], [50], [51], [52], [53], [54], [55], [56], [57], [58], [59], [60], [61], [62], [63], [64], [65], [66], [67], [68], [69], [70], [71], [72], [73], [74], [75], [76], [77], [78], [79], [80], [81], [82], [83], [84], [85], [86], [87], [88], [89], [90], [91], [92], [93], [94], [95], [96], [97], [98], [99], [100])
    ) p;
```